# Can't npm install react-native-workers

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to install [react-native-workers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-workers), but keep getting a bunch of errors in the build process (RN version - 0.33.0):

```
/node_modules/react-native-workers/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/Worker/core/ReactContextBuilder.java:7: error: cannot find symbol import com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl;  symbol:   class CatalystInstanceImpl   location: package com.facebook.react.bridge

/node_modules/react-native-workers/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/Worker/core/ReactContextBuilder.java:8: error: cannot find symbol import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader;   symbol:   class JSBundleLoader   location: package com.facebook.react.bridge

/node_modules/react-native-workers/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/Worker/core/ReactContextBuilder.java:9: error: cannot find symbol import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSCJavaScriptExecutor;   symbol:   class JSCJavaScriptExecutor   location: package com.facebook.react.bridge

/node_modules/react-native-workers/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/Worker/core/ReactContextBuilder.java:10: error: cannot find symbol import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptExecutor;   symbol:   class JavaScriptExecutor   location: package com.facebook.react.bridge

/node_modules/react-native-workers/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/Worker/core/ReactContextBuilder.java:15: error:  cannot find symbol import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry;   symbol:   class NativeModuleRegistry   location: package com.facebook.react.bridge

/node_modules/react-native-workers/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/Worker/core/ReactContextBuilder.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    private JSBundleLoader jsBundleLoader;   symbol:   class JSBundleLoader   location: class ReactContextBuilder

/node_modules/react-native-workers/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/Worker/core/ReactContextBuilder.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
    public ReactContextBuilder setJSBundleLoader(JSBundleLoader jsBundleLoader) {   symbol:   class JSBundleLoader   location: class ReactContextBuilder

/node_modules/react-native-workers/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/Worker/core/ReactContextBuilder.java:137: error: package NativeModuleRegistry does not exist
    private void addNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext, NativeModuleRegistry.Builder nativeRegistryBuilder) {

/node_modules/react-native-workers/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/Worker/core/ReactContextBuilder.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
        JavaScriptExecutor jsExecutor = new JSCJavaScriptExecutor.Factory().create(new WritableNativeMap());   symbol:   class JavaScriptExecutor   location: class ReactContextBuilder

/node_modules/react-native-workers/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/Worker/core/ReactContextBuilder.java:53: error: package JSCJavaScriptExecutor does not exist
        JavaScriptExecutor jsExecutor = new JSCJavaScriptExecutor.Factory().create(new WritableNativeMap());

/node_modules/react-native-workers/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/Worker/core/ReactContextBuilder.java:62: error: package NativeModuleRegistry does not exist
        NativeModuleRegistry.Builder nativeRegistryBuilder = new NativeModuleRegistry.Builder();

/node_modules/react-native-workers/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/Worker/core/ReactContextBuilder.java:62: error: package NativeModuleRegistry does not exist
        NativeModuleRegistry.Builder nativeRegistryBuilder = new NativeModuleRegistry.Builder();

/node_modules/react-native-workers/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/Worker/core/ReactContextBuilder.java:69: error: package CatalystInstanceImpl does not exist
        CatalystInstanceImpl.Builder catalystInstanceBuilder = new CatalystInstanceImpl.Builder()

/node_modules/react-native-workers/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/Worker/core/ReactContextBuilder.java:69: error: package CatalystInstanceImpl does not exist
        CatalystInstanceImpl.Builder catalystInstanceBuilder = new CatalystInstanceImpl.Builder()

14 errors :react-native-workers:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

I have noticed that those non-found symbols are imported from a wrong path (com.facebook.react.bridge) and are actually located in com.facebook.react.***cxxbridge***.

After fixing these up, I ended up with a single error:

```
constructor Factory in class Factory cannot be applied to given types;
        JavaScriptExecutor jsExecutor = new JSCJavaScriptExecutor.Factory().create(new WritableNativeMap());
                                        ^
  required: WritableNativeMap
  found: no arguments
```

At this point I've tried to change it to this:

```
JavaScriptExecutor jsExecutor = new JSCJavaScriptExecutor.Factory(new WritableNativeMap()).create();
```

And the build has passed, but then I'm getting an error saying that

> UIManager is undefined. The native module config is probably incorrect

I'm totally lost here, has anyone got this lib to work?
(React native version - 0.33.0, react-native-workers version - 0.3.1)

Comment: I have the same problem here... Did you get it working?

Comment: Ok, i got it. You have to dig deep in 
/node_modules/react-native-workers/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/Worker/core/UIManagerStubModule.java and add the @ReactNative annotation at the getName method.

The app runs now, but, the new runnable that is create by the Java code is dropped due to some exception. Any inputs?

Update: Well it works, after a fresh app install on the emulator!